# NiFi: Issues with creating and connecting RPG programmatically

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to write a function that takes two parameters, a processor ID in nifi instance A and an input port in nifi instance B and creates an RPG in nifi instance A which connects the above to.

Now, how I am doing that is

1. A POST to the /nifi-api/process-groups//remote-process-groups endpoint to create an RPG and retrieve the ID of that RPG
2. A POST to the /nifi-api/process-groups//connections endpoint to create a connection between the processor and the input port. the processorID and the ID of the input port are being provided along with the list of the relationships.
3. A final PUT to /nifi-api/remote-process-groups/ to enable the transmission between the machines.

Now, the function always throws errors in step 2. A 409 is thrown for the POST request with the error being 'Unable to find specified destination'. (though refreshing the canvas on machine 1 shows the rpg having been created)
However, when I manually run the steps 2 and 3 afterwards, with the same rpgid, the connection happens.

Now, I'm not sure if this is a synchronization issue or not, but I want to figure it out because I would not want to separate out steps 1 2 and 3. Could somebody point out what could be the issue here?

PS - the post messages for steps 2 are the same when the api is called from within the function and manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the RPG is created, it will kick off a background thread to discover available ports. I would suggest adding a step to continually poll GET /nifi-api/remote-process-group/{id} until the port your expecting is available. Once it is, you should be able to create the connection.

Comment: Would that mean just wait till I get a 200 response for the GET on that particular RPG id?

Comment: No, you'd what to inspect the result to ensure the port was discovered successfully. If may not be discovered if, for instance, the appropriate permissions are not in place or another user has removed the port. The RPG will continue to run that background so it always knows what ports of are available.

Comment: ah, understood what you meant. The available portId are present in the response json of the GET, that bit confused me.